# Spring Batch - Last item from the reader alone is getting updated

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have to read from a file (FlatFile) and update a column if that ID present in the file matches the id in the column.The file is being read properly but only the last id value is getting updated here . Please find the snippet

Job-Config.xml

```
<bean id="abcitemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="file:datafile/outputs/ibdData.txt" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">          
          <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="names" value="ID,NAM,TYPE" />
                <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
            </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="fieldSetMapper">  
          <bean class="com.pershing.intraware.springbatch.mapper.abcFieldsetMapper" />           
          </property>
          </bean>
      </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="abcitemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="sql"><value>UPDATE TEST_abc SET BIZ_ARNG_CD = CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TEST_abc WHERE ID= ? and MONTH=(to_char(sysdate, 'MM')) AND  YR =(to_char(sysdate, 'YY'))) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END</value></property>
    <!-- It will take care matching between object property and sql name parameter -->
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="testPrepStatementSetter" /> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

Setter.java

```
public class IDItemPreparedStatementSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Test>  {
  @Override
  public void setValues(Test item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ps.setString(1, item.getID());
  }     
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `WHERE ID = ?` at the end of query

Comment: Even if i add an where condition it behaves the same

Comment: I want to update a column as 'Y' if the ID is present in the file (read from the file Reader) is present in this DB Table. Else update it as 'N'

Comment: Looking your update query the behaviour you described in your question is correct; only last id will be used to update table because you are update all rows at every update

Comment: How do i modify it ? or what am i missing ?

Comment: I don't know; I can't understand exactly which is the goal you want to achive. If you want to update a column in a table the update stmt should contains a filter; that filter is missing in your sql phrase. Check it and correct. I can't help you more and I think this problem is not strictly SB related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is updating each row of database every time it is fired. You need to restrict that. Currently; it must be setting the BIZ_ARNG_CD to 'Y' for records with ID equal to the ID of the last record passed to the writer.

You can fix this in 2 ways -

1. Default the database column to 'N' and don't set it to 'N' in the update statement
2. Add where clause in update script ( BIZ_ARNG_CD != 'Y')